# Add label/string to UITableView programmatically like seen in iPhone Settings

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have an application with several tables separated exactly like seen in the Settings on the iPhone.  I would like to add a value to be displayed in this label exactly like seen for example in the Settings Wi-Fi or Bluetooth where on the right you have your item and on the left a value is displayed.  How can I do this?

Setting.h

```
@interface Setting : NSObject {

NSString *_settingsID;
NSString *_catalogID;
NSString *_category;
NSString *_facings;
NSString *_quantity;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *settingsID;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *catalogID;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *category;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *facings;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *quanity;

- (Setting *)initWithName:(NSString *)settingsID desc:(NSString *)category CategoryID:(NSString *)catalogID Facings:(NSString *)facings Quantity:(NSString *)quantity;

@end
```

Setting.m

```
@implementation Setting

@synthesize settingsID = _settingsID;
@synthesize catalogID = _catalogID;
@synthesize category = _category;
@synthesize facings = _facings;
@synthesize quanity = _quantity;

- (Setting *)initWithName:(NSString *)settingsID desc:(NSString *)category CategoryID:(NSString *)catalogID Facings:(NSString *)facings Quantity:(NSString *)quantity {

if ((self = [super init])) {

    self.settingsID = settingsID;
    self.catalogID = catalogID;
    self.category = category;
    self.facings = facings;
    self.quanity = quantity;
}

return self;

}

@end
```

Next in my connectionDidFinishLoading I have taken the result from the JSON call to my WebAPI and I populate this Setting object....

```
-(void) connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {

self.settings = [NSMutableArray array];

NSError *error = nil;

id result = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:receivedData options:kNilOptions error:&error];

if ([result isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {

    for (NSDictionary *item in result) {

        NSString *settingsID = [item objectForKey:@"ID"];
        NSString *category = [item objectForKey:@"Category"];
        NSString *categoryID = [item objectForKey:@"CatalogID"];
        NSString *facings = [item objectForKey:@"Facings"];
        NSString *quantity = [item objectForKey:@"Quantity"];

        Setting *setting = [[Setting alloc] initWithName:settingsID desc:category CategoryID:categoryID Facings:facings Quantity:quantity];

        [self.settings addObject:setting];

    }
}

for (Setting *item in self.settings) {

    NSString *frozen = @"Frozen";
    BOOL res = [frozen isEqualToString:item.category];

    if (res == TRUE) {

        **NSLog(@"Original Value: %@, Bool Value: %@", item.facings, item.facings.boolValue == false ? @"No" : @"Yes");
        NSLog(@"Original Value: %@, Bool Value: %@", item.quantity, item.quantity.boolValue == false ? @"No" : @"Yes");
        // Frozen
        appDelegate.frozen_facing_value = item.facings.boolValue == false ? @"No" : @"Yes";
        appDelegate.frozen_quantity_value = item.quantity.boolValue == false ? @"No" : @"Yes";**
    }

    NSString *fruit = @"Fruit";
    res = [fruit isEqualToString:item.category];

    if (res == TRUE) {

        // Fruit
    }

    NSString *salads = @"Salads";
    res = [salads isEqualToString:item.category];

    if (res == TRUE) {

        // Salads
    }

    NSString *vegetables = @"Vegetables";
    res = [vegetables isEqualToString:item.category];

    if (res == TRUE) {

        // Vegetables
    }
}

NSLog(@"Finished..");
finished = TRUE;
}
```

[image: When the page first loads...]

[image: After I pull down on the UI to get the cellFroRowAtIndexPath function to fire again...]

I synthesize my selected_value in AppDelegate.h and use this to store the value of the cell the user clicks on.

```
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate> {    
NSString *_selected_value;
**NSString *_frozen_facing_value;**
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

@property (strong, nonatomic) UINavigationController *navigationController;

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *selected_value;

**@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *frozen_facing_value;**

@end
```

AppDelegate.m

Here is my cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
UITableViewCell *result = nil;

if ([tableView isEqual:self.myTableView]){

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";

    result = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (result == nil){
        result = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    NSMutableArray *sectionArray = [self.arrayOfSections objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];

    result.textLabel.text = [sectionArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSString *res = (NSString *)result.textLabel.text;

    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    if ([[self tableView:tableView titleForHeaderInSection:indexPath.section] isEqualToString:@"Frozen"]) {

        if ([res isEqualToString:FACINGS]) {

           **result.detailTextLabel.text = appDelegate.frozen_facing_value;**

        } else if ([res isEqualToString:QUANTITY]) {

           result.detailTextLabel.text = @"Yes 2";
        }

    } else if ([[self tableView:tableView titleForHeaderInSection:indexPath.section] isEqualToString:@"Fruit"]) {

        if ([res isEqualToString:FACINGS]) {

            result.detailTextLabel.text = @"No 3";

        } else if ([res isEqualToString:QUANTITY]) {

            result.detailTextLabel.text = @"Yes 4";
        }

    } else if ([[self tableView:tableView titleForHeaderInSection:indexPath.section] isEqualToString:@"Salads"]) {

        if ([res isEqualToString:FACINGS]) {

            result.detailTextLabel.text = @"No 5";

        } else if ([res isEqualToString:QUANTITY]) {

            result.detailTextLabel.text = @"Yes 6";
        }

    } else if ([[self tableView:tableView titleForHeaderInSection:indexPath.section] isEqualToString:@"Vegetables"]) {

        if ([res isEqualToString:FACINGS]) {

            result.detailTextLabel.text = @"No 7";

        } else if ([res isEqualToString:QUANTITY]) {

            result.detailTextLabel.text = @"Yes 8";
        }
    }

    appDelegate.selected_value = result.detailTextLabel.text;

    result.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
}

return result;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

NSMutableArray *sectionArray = [self.arrayOfSections objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];

NSLog(@"Select value: %@", appDelegate.selected_value);

appDelegate.selectedSetting = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Select value: %@ for %@, in section: %@", @"Test", [sectionArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row], [self tableView:tableView titleForHeaderInSection:indexPath.section]];

[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

SettingsViewController *settings = [[SettingsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Settings" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:settings animated:YES];
}
```

In my log window I see "Select value: Yes 6" unless I scroll down.  The last value rendered to the table is what I end up seeing.  I know there is a better way to do this, I just don't know how.  Ideas/Suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to setup your table view cell with a style of UITableViewCellStyleValue1. This is the type used in the Settings app for showing a black title and a blue value.

The title is set for the cell with the titleLabel and the value on the right is set using the detailTextLabel property of the cell.

Look in the docs for UITableViewCell and the initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier: method.

Comment: Yes, I see UITableViewCellStyleValue1 is what I need.  I just need to figure out how to implement that.  http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: In the code you posted, replace the use of UITableViewCellStyleDefault with UITableCellStyleValue1. That's it. The rest of your code already sets the two labels.

Comment: I made the code change you suggested and updated my code above.  Now that I see the UI I was looking for, I wonder if you have a suggestion on doing this a little cleaner and getting the actual value on the right that the user clicks on.

Comment: You need some sort of data model to hold all of this. The last thing you should be doing is basing your code logic on header titles. Create a data model that represents your table structure. Then you extract the data based on the index path. Every table view data source and delegate method should be based on the data structures, not values you get from the view.

Comment: I do have that.  I have a Settings class.  I'll update the code above.  I have a JSON call that populates that.  My next step was to take the values I have in that model set the right label in the table to that value.  See above...

Comment: The rear problem I am running in to is how do I assign the values from my Setting object to the label on the right of each table cell.  The only was I can think to do it is to populate an array in self and based on the table header assign that value by iterating through self.settings for the category that matches the table header....is this a good approach?

Comment: OK, after the last update I am able to see the value in the detail label in the table view on the right as I expect from my data model.  The problem I am now having is I ONLY see this value after I scroll down the UI and then scroll up again.  I see that the connectionDidFinishLoading event happens AFTER cellForRowAtIndexPath.  I tried [self.tableView reloadData] at the end of both of these functions with no different results.  I don't get the data I need from the JSON call until the connectionDidFinishLoading has completed.  Help please :-)

Comment: I need to figure out to get my values: Yes/No seen in the second screen shot above to show up without having to pull down on the screen.  I have tried to use [self.tableView reloadData] in the connectionDidFinishLoading and cellForRowAtIndexPath functions but I am not having any luck.